# Connecting Oracle Database 11g in ArcMap?

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcmap, oracle-spatial, direct-connect

I installed Oracle Database Enterprise Edition 11g(11.2.0.1) in my machine. And I installed ArcMap Desktop 10.3.1 on another machine. Whenever I am trying to create a direct connection of Oracle DB from ArcMap without ArcSDE installation, I am getting the following error like "Failed to connect to the specified server. Do you want to continue? Bad login user". Even I have enabled the port in Oracle DB machine. I was giving the oracle server is the DB IPAddress, Instance Name is "orcl" and port is 1521.

Do I need to install Oracle Client software where the Oracle DB is existing and, if not, where I am lacking in this concept?

Comment: You don't need a Client on the database server, but you certainly do on the Desktop machine. More importantly, you need a supported Oracle install on the server, and a client compatible with that. If the database has not been geodatabase enabled, you will be limited to Query Layer, Query Table, and simple SQL access. Login errors are generally just that, whic means you need to provide exact details of your connection parameters (less password, of course).

Comment: Thanks for your response. Once again I will verify the connection parameters.